# Https certificate warning and wrong issued to domain

Tags: 2013, security, https

our web site registered with a Digicert security certificate and with our domain, but when we open home page it shows a security alert dialog box

The name on the security certificate is invalid or does not match the name of the site, and when i check view certificate it issued to different domain rather than our domain, how this happen and how to solve this certificate issue?
[image]

wrong domain certificate warning:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the url to the domain which mentioned in the Certificate fix the issue, otherwise, Only solutions is you have to create a new certificate with proper configuration( proper domains name).

> The common name that you specified when you generated the certificate
>   request for that Web site does not match the URL that is used to
>   access the Web site. For example, if you access the site by typing an
>   IP address or the server name, but the common name that is specified
>   in the certificate request is www.adatum.com, you receive the security
>   message.

To avoid this warning, make sure that the common name that is specified when you generate the certificate request matches the URL that will be used to access the site.

If the URL that will be used to access the site cannot be changed to match the common name on the certificate, follow these steps:
Create another certificate request. Make sure that the common name matches the

1. URL that is used to access the Web site.
2. Have your certification authority generate a new certificate.
3. Use the new certificate for the Web site.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813618

Comment: hi when i did fiddler trace i found  our website calling some twitter apis to get latest tweets from our site twitter account, and also we are using google analytics in our site, and our site protected under F5 firewall rules.

Comment: we added twitter apis in our site last two months back here  i don't know why this security certificate warning came